# While loop prematurely breaks using multiple conditions

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm writing a small program in C and I don't want my `while` loop to exit until two conditions are met.

This is an example of my problem:

```
int a, b, x;
a = 3;
b = 5;
x = 0;
while(x <= a && x <= b)
    {
        //do stuff
        x++;
    }
```

The loop breaks when `x == a` but `x != b`. This would evaluate to `false && true` which should return `false` however it still breaks regardless.

Why is my loop ending early?

Comment: Are you *sure* that the loop is breaking then? Can you provide more of the actual code that you're using and why you believe this is the case?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how a while loop's condition works. It loops while the condition is true.

Comment: How exactly the conditions off the loop relate to the sentence after the code?

Comment: @Jashaszun Oh, I think I mixed up the end values, so actually when `x == a` and `x != b` that would be the same as `false && true` which should still return `false`. I'll make the corrections.

Comment: @PairedPrototype Yes, it will return `false`, and thus your while loop will stop.

Comment: Do you really mean __until__ or __while__? C has no until loops

Comment: The OP is confused and has probably made a mistake. Lets not make him more nervous by down voting this too much.

Comment: When the condition is false, the loop breaks. That's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Haris I agree, this isn't a terrible question, just a misunderstanding. It's not low quality IMO. It does show lack of research, though.

Comment: Yes, in all honesty, I could (and should) have spent longer looking at my issue and would have figured it out. I'm well aware that the loop continues until `while(false)`, it's just been a long day and time is of the essence currently.

But thank you SO comunity for opening my eyes again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You answered half your question correctly, let me repeat and correct you.

The loop breaks when `x > a` or `x < b` (`x = 4`). This would evaluate to `true && false` which should return `false` **hence the loop is breaking.**

---

Remember, when using `&&` both the condition has to be `true` for the overall condition to be `true`.

Therefore, if you want your loop to exit **only** when both the condition is false then use `||`

```
int a, b, x;
a = 3;
b = 5;
x = 0;
while(x <= a || x <= b)
    {
        //do stuff
        x++;
    }
```

Now, untill both the condition is `false`, your loop should run.

Comment: Ah, it all makes sense now. I'm having a dumb moment. This has indeed fixed my issue. I will select as the answer as soon as the time delay is up.

Comment: @PairedPrototype, Great. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the logical `and` (&&) operator which isn't valid in this context. Your loop isn't breaking prematurely, it's breaking when x is later than 3, which is right. Instead you want to use the logical `or` operator, which is known as a double pipe (||)